# Enable submit button after all droppable div is filled

Tags: jquery, html

I am making one quiz using jquery. below is the screen snap.

[image]

This quiz is drag and drop kind of quiz. all work is done and successful.  Now I have an issue regarding **enable submit button**.

**Requirements are**

1. A button must be disabled when page load - done
2. options should be draggable and droppable in blank space - done

**What is not done?**

after **both** items get dragged in blank space button should be enabled

please see my jquery regarding this. and tell me where I am making mistake

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.selected_answer1' && '.selected_answer2').on('drop change', function (event, ui){ 
          alert('dropped');
            if (jQuery(this).drop()) {
                jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop('disabled', false);
                alert('dropped')
            }
            else {
                jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
});
```

**about class name** -

.selected_answer1 - 1st blank space

.selected_answer2 - 2nd blank space

.fillinblank_button - submit button

**Jsfiddle link** - https://jsfiddle.net/vaishuk/ajmuse3v/

PS - I want to do this with jquery, not js.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a kinda demo to check?

Comment: Add some html so that we have something to work with.

Comment: what's your jquery version ?

Comment: okay.. I am Adding it

Comment: its 3.3.1 @RAJNIKPATEL

Comment: @PraveenKumar Jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/vaishuk/ajmuse3v/

Comment: @AntonyMN I have added it

Comment: @vaishalikapadia Checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved condition in `drop: function(event, ui){}`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // This code used for set order attribute for items
var numberOfItems = jQuery("#options").find(".drag-text").length;
jQuery.each(jQuery("#options").find(".drag-text"), function(index, item) {
    jQuery(item).attr("order", index);
    var removeBotton = jQuery('<i class="fa fa-times cancel_btn" style="display:none"></i>');
    removeBotton.click(function(){
        addToOlderPlace(jQuery(this).parent());        
      });
    jQuery(item).append(removeBotton);
    
});
  
  jQuery('.selected_answer1, .selected_answer2').droppable({
    accept: ".drag-text",

    drop: function(event, ui) {

    //jQuery(".fillinblank_button").attr("disabled",false);

    // Check for existing another option
    if(jQuery(this).find(".drag-text").length > 0)
    addToOlderPlace(jQuery(this).find(".drag-text"));

      jQuery(ui.draggable).find("i").attr("style","");
      jQuery(this).append(jQuery(ui.draggable)); 


if(jQuery('.selected_answer1').html().length > 0 && jQuery('.selected_answer2').html().length > 0){
               jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop('disabled', false);

    }
    else{
      jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop('disabled', true);
    }

    }
    
    
    
  });

  jQuery(".drag-text").draggable({
    helper:"clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  }); 
  
  
  // This function used for find old place of item
  function addToOlderPlace(jQueryitem) {
        var indexItem = jQueryitem.attr("order");
        var itemList = jQuery("#options").find(".drag-text");
        jQueryitem.find("i").hide();         

        if (indexItem === "0")
            jQuery("#options").prepend(jQueryitem);
        else if (Number(indexItem) === (Number(numberOfItems)-1))        
             jQuery("#options").append(jQueryitem);                       
        else
            jQuery(itemList[indexItem - 1]).after(jQueryitem);
    }
    
})


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.fillinblank_button').click(function() {

 if (jQuery('.selected_answer1').find('#ca-one')) {
    jQuery('.selected_answer1 #ca-one').css({'color':'#0d9f3e'});
    jQuery('.selected_answer2 #ca-two').css({'color':'#0d9f3e'});
    jQuery('.answer_section').slideDown();
    jQuery(".drag-text").draggable({ disabled: true });
    jQuery('.selected_answer1, .selected_answer2').find('i').hide();
    jQuery('span.selected_answer1').css({'color':'#f73c55'});
    jQuery('span.selected_answer2').css({'color':'#f73c55'});
     //alert('right selected');
    }
});

});




/*
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop('disabled', true);
     jQuery('.selected_answer1, .selected_answer2').on('drop', function () {
        if(jQuery(this).val() != '') {
          alert('dropped')
           jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     });
 });

 */


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.selected_answer1' && '.selected_answer2').on('drop change', function (event, ui){ 

            
        });
});
```

```css
/*===== activity ======*/

.aat_common .actiity_main { width: 100%; display: inline-block; padding:25px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);border-radius: 7px; border-bottom: 9px solid #2a9af3; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_heading { width: 100%; display: inline-block; background-color: #f3f4f6; padding: 22px 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_heading h2 { padding-left:20px; font-size:14px; text-transform: uppercase; position: relative; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;  color:#3b3a3c; margin-top: 0; } 
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_heading h2:before {position: absolute; top: 18%; left: 0; content: ""; width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: #67cb50; border-radius: 50%; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_heading p { font-size: 16px; color:#a3a3a3; position: relative; padding-left: 28px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_heading p:before {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; content:url('../../../content/lessons/72/images/tip-arrow.png');  }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select {width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select p { font-weight: bold; color:#252327; }

.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .answer_select {width: 100%; padding: 0px 25px; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .tf_answer { padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px !important; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .answer_select label {font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 12px; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .tf_answer label { margin-bottom: 5px !important; }

.containerr {display: inline-block; position: relative;padding-left: 35px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 22px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
.containerr input {position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;}

.checkmark1, .true-false1 {position: absolute;top: 22%;left: 0;height: 13px;width: 13px; border-radius: 50%; border:2px solid #5e5f60;}
.checkmark2, .true-false2 {position: absolute;top: 39%;left: 4px;height: 5px;width: 5px; border-radius: 50%; }
.checkmark3, .true-false3 {position: absolute;top: 22%;left: 0;height: 13px;width: 13px; border-radius: 50%; border:2px solid #5e5f60;}
.checkmark4, .true-false4 {position: absolute;top: 39%;left: 4px;height: 5px;width: 5px; border-radius: 50%; }
.checkmark5, .true-false5 {position: absolute;top: 22%;left: 0;height: 13px;width: 13px; border-radius: 50%; border:2px solid #5e5f60;}
.checkmark6, .true-false6 {position: absolute;top: 39%;left: 4px;height: 5px;width: 5px; border-radius: 50%; }
.checkmark7, .true-false7 {position: absolute;top: 22%;left: 0;height: 13px;width: 13px; border-radius: 50%; border:2px solid #5e5f60;}
.checkmark8, .true-false8 {position: absolute;top: 39%;left: 4px;height: 5px;width: 5px; border-radius: 50%; }
.true-false9 {position: absolute;top: 22%;left: 0;height: 13px;width: 13px; border-radius: 50%; border:2px solid #5e5f60;}
.true-false10 {position: absolute;top: 39%;left: 4px;height: 5px;width: 5px; border-radius: 50%; }
.true-false11 {position: absolute;top: 22%;left: 0;height: 13px;width: 13px; border-radius: 50%; border:2px solid #5e5f60;}
.true-false12 {position: absolute;top: 39%;left: 4px;height: 5px;width: 5px; border-radius: 50%; }

.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark1, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false1 {border:2px solid #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark2, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false2 {background-color: #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark3, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false3 {border:2px solid #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark4, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false4 {background-color: #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark5, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false5 {border:2px solid #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark6, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false6 {background-color: #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark7, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false7 {border:2px solid #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .checkmark8, .containerr input:checked ~ .true-false8 {background-color: #2196f3;}

.containerr input:checked ~ .true-false9 {border:2px solid #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .true-false10 {background-color: #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .true-false11 {border:2px solid #2196f3;}
.containerr input:checked ~ .true-false12 {background-color: #2196f3;}

.checkmark_button { width: 135px; background-color: #2a9af3; text-align:center; color:#a3a3a3; color:#fff; padding: 17px 0px; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;  margin-left: 4%; margin-top: 20px; transition: .5s ease-in-out; cursor: pointer; }

.tf_button { cursor: default !important; outline:none; width: 135px; background-color: #f3f4f6; text-align:center; color:#a3a3a3; padding: 17px 0px; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;  margin-left: 4%; margin-top: 20px; transition: .5s ease-in-out;}

.fillinblank_button { width: 135px; background-color: #2a9af3; text-align:center; color:#a3a3a3; color:#fff; padding: 17px 0px; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;  margin-left: 4%; margin-top: 20px; transition: .5s ease-in-out; cursor: pointer; }

.aat_common .actiity_main .answer_section {width: 100%; display: inline-block; display: none; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .answer_section h2 { color: #17b045; font-size: 16px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: 600;}
.aat_common .actiity_main .answer_section h3 {font-size: 17px !important; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: 600; color:#505152; }

.aat_common .actiity_main .answer_section ol li,
.aat_common .actiity_main .answer_section ul li { list-style-type: upper-latin; font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; color: #818282; }

.aat_common .actiity_main .tf_answer ol li,
.aat_common .actiity_main .tf_answer ul li { margin-top:20px; list-style-type: upper-latin; font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;  }

.aat_common .actiity_main .answer_section .b-col ol li { color: #252327 !important; margin-top: 0px !important;}

.checkmark_disable {background-color: #f3f4f6 !important; color:#a3a3a3 !important; cursor: default;}
.checkmark_enable { background-color: #2a9af3 !important; color:#fff !important; cursor: pointer !important; }


/*.tolerance_calculation*/

.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drag-dropp { width: 100%; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drag-dropp ul  { color:#252327; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drag-dropp ul li { list-style-type: decimal; color:#252327; position: relative;}
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drag-dropp ul li p  { color:#252327;  margin: 0px 0px 10px;}
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drgable-content ul {padding-left: 50px; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drgable-content ul li { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px !important;  }


.selected_answer1 {position:  absolute; top: 0; left: 20%; width: 160px; height: 28px; border-bottom: 1px solid #959595; text-align: center; color:#565657; }
.selected_answer2 {position:  absolute; top: 0; left: 53%; width: 160px; height: 28px; border-bottom: 1px solid #959595; text-align: center; color:#565657; }
.selected_answer3 { display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 28px; border-bottom: 1px solid #959595; text-align: center; color:#565657; }


.spacing_text {position:  absolute; top: 0; left: 43%; color:#252327;  }

.options p { width: 100%; }
.cancel_btn { margin-left: 10px;}

.selectedd {color:#0d9f3e !important;}

.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drgable-content .drag-text { width: 200px; padding-left:40px; margin: 0px 0px 10px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px !important; position: relative; color:#565657; }
.aat_common .actiity_main .activity_select .drgable-content .drag-text:before {width:7px; height:7px; border-radius: 50%; background-color:#565657; position:  absolute; content:""; top: 35%; left: 5%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="aat_common">

<div class="actiity_main">

<div class="activity_heading">
<h2>FILL IN THE BLANK QUESTION</h2>
<p>Tip - Complete the sentences below by dragging the correct answer from the options given</p>
</div>

<div class="activity_select">
<p>Which ONE of the following statements is a benefit to the shareholders of a limited company?</p>

<div class="drag-dropp">

<ul start="1">
<li><p>A sole trader has<span class="selected_answer1 ui-droppable" id="enable-true1"></span> <span class="spacing_text">to prepare annual accounts by a certain date.</span></p></li>
<li><p>A charity is managed on a day-to-day basis by its <span class="selected_answer2 ui-droppable" id="enable-true1"></span> </p></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div class="drgable-content">
<div id="options">
<div class="drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="ca-one" order="0">A requirement<i class="fa fa-times cancel_btn" style="display:none"></i></div>
<div class="drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" order="1">No requirement<i class="fa fa-times cancel_btn" style="display:none"></i></div>
<div class="drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="ca-two" order="2">Trustees<i class="fa fa-times cancel_btn" style="display:none"></i></div>
<div class="drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" order="3">Directors<i class="fa fa-times cancel_btn" style="display:none"></i></div>
<div class="drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" order="4">Shareholders<i class="fa fa-times cancel_btn" style="display:none"></i></div>
</div>
</div>

<button class="fillinblank_button" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="">Submit</button>

<div class="answer_section">

<h2>Answer</h2>

<ol start="1">
<li>Although a sole trader has no specified submission deadlines in the way that a limited company does, the final accounts must be prepared in sufficient time to allow the owner to complete their personal tax return by the deadline.</li>
<li>A charity is run on a day-to-day basis by the trustees appointed.</li>
</ol>

</div>

</div>


</div>

<!--

<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             jQuery('.drag-text').draggable();
            
           jQuery('.selected_answer1' && '.selected_answer2').droppable({
                drop: function() {
                alert('dropped');
                  jQuery('.fillinblank_button').prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });

</script>

-->

           
           
                   
          

                                  </div>
```

Comment: whoo.. it's working...Can you please explain what was wrong?

Comment: I have removed condition `if (jQuery(this).drop()) {}`. if you want to check blank is filled or not please find out other way to check condition.

Comment: but it should only enable if both answer is dropped. here its working based on 2nd answer. :(

Comment: Yes, that's why I am saying something wrong with that condition you need to find out other way to check for that.

Comment: @vaishalikapadia Now check it's working with condition :)